# Vector pointer and push_back()

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, push-back

If I have

```
void f(vector<object> *vo) {

}
```

And I pass the address of a vector to f

```
vector<object> vo;
f(&vo);
```

How would I use `push_back()` to add to the vector?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dereference the pointer:

```
(*vo).push_back(object());
vo->push_back(object()); // short-hand
```

Note this is a basic concept of the language, you may benefit from reading a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

---

Note this has a glaring shortcoming:

```
f(0); // oops, dereferenced null; undefined behavior (crash)
```

To make your function safe, you need to correctly handle all valid pointer values (yes, null is a valid value). Either add a check of some kind:

```
if (!vo) return;
// or:
if (!vo) throw std::invalid_argument("cannot be null, plz");
```

Or make your function inherently correct by using a reference:

```
void f(vector<object>& vo) // *must* reference a valid object, null is no option
{
    vo.push_back(object()); // no need to dereference, no pointers; a reference
}
```

Now the onus is on the caller of the function to provide you with a valid reference.

Comment: I personally would suggest reference first, but +1 for showing both.